# \begin{frame} on input line 181 ended by \end{beamer@framepauses}. \end{frame}

Tags: beamer

```
\begin{frame}
Find the 2nd derivative, locate local extrema, find the points of inflection,
and discuss concavity, for the function $f(x)= x^{3} + 10x^{2} + 25x -50}$.

\begin{displaymath}
    f'(x)= 3x^{2} + 20x + 25 = 0
\end{displaymath}.
We find critical points at $\frac{-5}{3},\frac{137}{2}$.
Find the 2nd derivative, $f(x)=6x+20=0$, which gives us possible points of inflection.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Merely adding `\end{document}` at the end doesn't make the code compilable. Please follow the link posted in my comment above and read what you find at the end of that link; it will tell you how to produce a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), which, in general, is the only form of code acceptable in a question on this site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to stem from a missing brace (although a complete diagnostic would only be possible with an MWE, which is missing).

Comment: @Jubobs On the other hand, if the question was well written, it would be useful, since it seems that this is a mistake that can happen to anyone, and the error message is then googlable if this question exists.

Comment: @tohecz Are you suggesting that this question remain open? I'm pretty sure the site has an abundance of such questions that have been (justifiably, IMO) closed by now. If you allow such questions to remain open, then you open the gates to many many variants, to which the answer is invariably "you forgot a brace, there". I salute you for your answer (which I upvoted), but I don't think the site should be flooded with such low-value questions. I want to know what you think. We can talk about it in chat or on meta, if you want.

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra `}` by the end of this line:

```
and discuss concavity, for the function $f(x)= x^{3} + 10x^{2} + 25x -50}$
```

I'm not sure that this can cause the error you mention, however, this compiles now:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Find the 2nd derivative, locate local extrema, find the points of inflection,
and discuss concavity, for the function $f(x)= x^{3} + 10x^{2} + 25x -50$.

\[
    f'(x)= 3x^{2} + 20x + 25 = 0
\]
We find critical points at $\frac{-5}{3},\frac{137}{2}$.
Find the 2nd derivative, $f(x)=6x+20=0$, which gives us possible points of inflection.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Notice I have replaced `displaymath` environment by `\[...\]` which is shorter and has the same effect. And next time, please post a **full Minimal Working Example**, as Jubobs requested in the comment.